# Regex on url in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've NEVER been good with regular expressions despite my efforts.
Can someone please help me out I'm trying to match urls in this format:

```
"/year/monthnum/day/postname/"
```

so:

```
"2012/05/03/whatever-the-text-here"
```

using:

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(...))
{
 //do something
}
```

I've tried a couple of things but I'm just terrible with regex... Can someone help me out here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://regexr.com?30ram

```
if(window.location.pathname.match(/\/?[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2}\/.+$/))
```

*this can be enhanced also to check that day is not 0... or things like that...
but i think its enough.*

Comment: Awesome.. thanks very much Royi, one day I will find the time to spend a whole day getting to grips with regex but it's always been a minefield to me..

Comment: @Alex i'll be glad to help you with that. you can reference me with any question.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
if (/(?:(?:\d{4})[\\\/](?:\d{2})[\\\/](?:\d{2})[\\\/])([^\\\/]+)/m.test(subject)) {
    // Successful match
} else {
    // Match attempt failed
}
```

Comment: @stema:Right, but it could supports both the slashes, hence the effort!

Comment: hey Cylian, Thanks for your help, I've gone with the other simply because I understand whats going on better which is a little unfiar because I really dont understand regex too well but it will make it easier for me if I need to work with it

Comment: @Alex: You're welcome. You may visit [here](http://www.regexbuddy.com/) for a reference on RegEx.

Answer (score 0):

may this url help you out more in URL regular expression

http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1